# Copy multiple ranges with VBA

Tags: excel, copy, vba

I am trying to copy multiple ranges using Excel VBA. I understand that in order to select multiple ranges, syntax similar to that below is used:

```
Range("A1:B4000, F1:F4000").Select
```

This works fine in *selecting* the appropriate range. However, the following:

```
Range("A1:B4000, F1:F4000").Copy
```

...only copies the A1:B4000 range. This is the first problem I am facing.

Secondly, I would like to dynamically copy the data to the bottom row, which is not necessarily row #4000. If selecting a single range, the syntax is as follows:

```
Range("A1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Copy
```

The above code successfully copies everything from A1 to the bottom of the B column. I can't find any material on the net explaining how to do this for multiple selections.

What I'm essentially trying to do is copy A1:B(bottom) and F1:F(bottom), but the above two issues are stopping me. I assume this is a syntax issue..?

Comment: Can you just do a loop and copy and paste twice (so copy and paste the first range and then copy and paste the second range)?  It seems that since you are using VBA, you are adding extra complexity by trying to do it all in one step.

Comment: Yep, I could do that - that's my current workaround. I just hate workarounds :P

Comment: I just used your code and it worked fine for me (it copied the three columns and pasted them side by side below).  What version of Excel are you on?

Comment: Have a look at `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`.  That's the easiest path to dynamic ranges, if your data meets the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Scott Holtzman provided the solution in a comment:

> I would just adjust the following, since the OP asked for dynamic
>   range names, Set range1 = Range("A1:B" & Range("B" &
>   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) to get the real last cell in column B. Do
>   the same for column F as well

Answer (score 4):

Use the "Union" method.

```
Dim range1 as Range, range2 as Range, multipleRangeAs Range    
Set range1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B4000")    
Set range2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F4000")    
Set multipleRange= Union(range1, range2)
```

Then you can mess around with mutipleRange as per normal.

Comment: I would just adjust the following, since the OP asked for dynamic range names, `Set range1 = Range("A1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` to get the real last cell in column B. Do the same for column F as well.