# Copy and paste multiple ranges without using the clipboard using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am successfully copying values from a single range with the following code :

```
Dim wb As Workbook, strFile As String, rSrc As Range, rDst As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'pasting Summary values

    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\data\Summary.csv")
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rSrc = wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Range("b2:G" & LastRow)
        wb.Activate
        Set rDst = wb.Sheets("Summary").Cells(6, 4).Resize(rSrc.Rows.Count, rSrc.Columns.Count)
        rDst = rSrc.Value
```

I am also trying to copy multiple ranges from the same sheet but it crashes when I set the range of the source with the following code:

```
'PY to Comparison
    With wkbTemp.Sheets(1)

    Set r1 = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    Set r2 = .Range("d2:d" & LastRow)
    Set r3 = .Range("f2:g" & LastRow)
    Set r = Union(r1, r2, r3)
    Set rSrc = .Range(r)

    End With

    wb.Activate
    Set rDst = wb.Sheets("Comparison").Cells(9, 6).Resize(rSrc.Rows.Count, rSrc.Columns.Count)
    rDst = rSrc.Value
```

The above way to copy multiple ranges got it from the following link [Copy multiple ranges with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465368/copy-multiple-ranges-with-vba)

I also tried to copy the ranges using predefined length of rows (but what I really need is dynamic length), but my code only copies the first range:

```
Set rSrc = wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B6,d2:d6,f2,g6")   

    wb.Activate
    Set rDst = wb.Sheets("Comparison").Cells(9, 6).Resize(rSrc.Rows.Count, rSrc.Columns.Count)
    rDst = rSrc.Value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rSrc` will contain 3 `Areas`.  AFAIK, the default will be to use `rSrc.Areas(1).Value` if you don't specify which one to use.

Comment: You just can't do it that way - you'll need to use a loop.

Comment: Tim is right.  Loop over the Areas collection - each Area is a contiguous range

Comment: r is already a range so you cannot say set srcrg=.range(r) . Next time use option explicit. Ditch r, and directly set srcrg=union(....). But you need to test if srcrg is nothing too....

Comment: @chrisneilsen I am trying to do that but I am doing something wrong. please see my code below

Comment: @TimWilliams I am trying to do that but I am doing something wrong. please see my code below

Comment: Exactly how should the three different areas be pasted?

Comment: @TimWilliams beginning at `Cells(9,6)`, all areas together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
'...
With wkbTemp.Sheets(1)
    Set r1 = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    Set r2 = .Range("d2:d" & LastRow)
    Set r3 = .Range("f2:g" & LastRow)
    Set r = Union(r1, r2, r3)
End With

CopyRangeValue r, wb.Sheets("Comparison").Cells(9, 6)
'....
```

`CopyRangeValue` Sub looks like this:

```
'copy a range (can be multi-area) value to a different range
Sub CopyRangeValue(rngCopy As Range, rngDest As Range)
    Dim a As Range
    For Each a In rngCopy.Areas
        rngDest.Resize(a.Rows.Count, a.Columns.Count).Value = a.Value
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, a.Columns.Count)
    Next a
End Sub
```