# Copy multiple ranges (dynamic) without selecting them

Tags: vba, excel

**QUESTION**

How can I perform a copy of a list of cells, without selecting them? 
Say I want to copy the ranges `A1`, `A5` and `A7`.
They are stored in a string like this: `addr = "A1,A5,A7"`

If I select them first and copy them, the action works fine:

```
Range(addr).Select
Selection.Copy
```

When I paste from my clipboard, I only have the values I selected.

Also, if I perform a `Union` of `Range` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465368/copy-multiple-ranges-with-vba), it would work too without selecting:

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rngUnion As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1")
Set rng2 = Range("A5")
Set rng3 = Range("A7")
Set rngUnion = Union(rng1,rng2,rng3)
rngUnion.Copy
```

However, I cannot *neither* select the ranges first, *nor* knowing before runtime how many ranges I will have to select.

I've tried to do this:

```
Range(addr).Copy
```

but when I perform the paste it takes all the values between A1 and A7 (basically `A1:A7`).

How can I get to copy the single cells without selecting them or uniting them?

**BACKGROUND - not necessary to answer the question I guess**

I have a listbox in which there is a list of values, that the user can multi-select (they can select like the first, the fourth, the seventh line etc.).

When they do that, I build a collection containing those values:

```
["value1", "value2", "value3", ... ]
```

Those values are unique in the spreadsheet (if I run a `Find`, I only can find one range). 
As you can guess, I don't know in advance how many values there will be in the collection.

What I need to do is to make them copy their selection. Hence, I build a collection based on those values:

```
For j = 0 To Me.longList.ListCount - 1
    If Me.longList.Selected(j) Then
        tmpColl.Add Split(Split(Me.longList.List(j), " ")(1), " ")(0) '<-- add the story ID to the collection
    End If
Next j
```

and then, I build the string holding the address of my multi-selection:

```
For j = 1 To tmpColl.Count
    With Sheets("Stories list")
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A10000").Find(tmpColl(j), lookAt:=xlWhole)
        addr = addr & "$A$" & rng.Row & ","
    End With
Next j

addr = Left(addr, Len(addr) - 1)
```

Comment: I'm confused because `Range(addr).Copy` copies just those three cells when I test it.

Comment: You will need to loop through the suggestion copy and paste one at a time, or put them in an array one at a time, then assign the whole array at once to the output.

Comment: @SJR very strange, it doesn't work on my side...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work without needing to select the entries. It will split the cell addresses into an array, then iterate those to add the values into a new array for outputting to a sheet.

I've put values in A1,A3,A5, and that will move it to column B. All the code assumes this is working on the ActiveSheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SO_Example()
    'Assign a string with the range you want to add
    Dim addStr As String: addStr = "A1,A3,A5"

    'Split the string by a comma to create an array of cells
    Dim cellArr As Variant: cellArr = Split(addStr, ",")
    Dim i As Long

    'Resize the OutArray to be as large as the number of cells to select
    Dim arrOut As Variant: ReDim arrOut(UBound(cellArr))

    'Add the items to the array
    For i = LBound(cellArr) To UBound(cellArr)
        arrOut(i) = Range(cellArr(i)).Value
    Next

    'Output to column B
    Range("B1:B" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrOut)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I am already building the "addStr" myself, so I might directly build the content of "arrOut" instead of building "addStr" first and split it then. I wanted to actually perform a real "Selection.Copy" of the ranges in order to bring along the hyperlinks, but I guess I will move to this direction and re-build everything myself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can always build a formula using `=Hyperlink()` using the same method. Or alternatively, get the `.Formula` property instead of `.Value`